Is it possible to add classes to the nav element created by the paginator's links() method?
For example, using $users->links() would create:
<nav class="pagination-nav">
    <ul class="pagination">
        ...
    </ul>
<nav>

and I want to add custom class to the nav element:
<nav class="pagination-nav my-custom-class">
    <ul class="pagination">
        ...
    </ul>
<nav>


Laravel’s pagination templates are stored in resources/views/vendor/pagination. If you don’t have these files, you can publish them with:
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination

This will copy Laravel’s default pagination views to resources/views/vendor/pagination. You can edit the bootstrap-4.blade.php or tailwind.blade.php file (depending on which pagination style you use).
Open the appropriate file, such as bootstrap-4.blade.php or tailwind.blade.php.
Locate the  tag and add your custom class:
<nav class="pagination-nav my-custom-class" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination Navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>


Exactly. See https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view
